# How I can getelement on a "X" site and show in "Y" site mine

Tags: vbscript

I want to capture just selected elements "Raid Boss Status", but I want capture just the raid boss that I say the name for. Example: I want to capture in [this site](http://zionweb.l2cr.com/gamecpc6/index.php) just: Baium, Antharas and Valakas.

I want to capture just that Boss and save it in a new HTML or text file, and if possible I want separate Deads and Alives, and show the importants boss when Lives sending one warning to me see. When one importante boss respawn send to me one alert.

I had the login working.

```vb
WScript.Quit Main

Function Main
  Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "http://zionweb.l2cr.com/gamecpc6/index.php"
  'IE.top = 0
  'IE.left = 1370
  'IE.Height = 770
  'IE.Width = 650
  Wait IE
  With IE.Document
    IE.Document.getElementsByName("username")(0).value = "CHECKBOSS"
    IE.Document.getElementsByName("password")(0).value = "123456"
    IE.Document.forms(0).submit
  End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub

Sub IE_OnQuit
  On Error Resume Next
  WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "IE closed before script finished."
  WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Javascript, and your site requires authentication so no one is able to go and get context of your question.